# inheritance of pentaho log kettle.properties in sub transforms

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I have setup to log Pentaho jobs and transformations to a database

This works fine provided I define every job and every transformation in its individual log settings dialogue.

I see that I can configure the kettle properties file to hold these values.
However I can't get this to inherit autoamtically in a transformation when it is called by a job. I assume that if defined in properties it should just inherit and work.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Thanks

(MS windows env with MS Sql server- we don't have Pentaho enterprise).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding below entries in "kettle.properties" file.

`kettle logging properties`

KETTLE_TRANS_LOG_DB=

KETTLE_TRANS_LOG_SCHEMA=

KETTLE_TRANS_LOG_TABLE=etl_trans_log

KETTLE_JOB_LOG_DB=

KETTLE_JOB_LOG_SCHEMA=

KETTLE_JOB_LOG_TABLE=etl_job_log

Comment: Hi I have defined these properties and it works at the job level with no log settings  in the job log tab. However the transformations the job calls the logs are not generated. The logs only generate if I define logging in every transformation on its logging tab. ie Properties don't force logging when I think this is what should happen. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have foound that provided I set the proerties file on the machine and then set each transformation by right clicking and setting each log to have the connection, then when I call the job it all logs correctly.

So you need the database connection in all transforms and you need to set this a sdefault in the logging tab.

I think this is right anyway unless someone else has a shorter cut